# Is there any reasonably big web application (e.g 1M page views/month ) running on mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, mono

I have plans to work on a website using mono and asp.net mvc.But i would like to know where anyone has actually used mono for reasonably big production environment.

Comment: What do you mean under `1M page views`? The number of views i.e. users? This characteristics is about web server rather than programming framework

Comment: what i meant is that if apache/mono can serve few  million pages per month without crashing,it means the framework is reasonably stable.

Answer (score 2):

Does [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) count? [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/) too is developed in Mono. These are probably the two most-cited examples of "large" Mono products. If you're specifically after web-sites developed in Mono, then I'm afraid I've no knowledge in that area.

Comment: sorry i just edited the question.I was asking about web applications

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to do some testing yourself, it's not hard, and different apps will behave differently.

You can write your own simple test harness or use something like OpenSTA http://opensta.org
There's a few more links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing

The thing to be mindful of is that Web apps scale out, not up (more servers, not bigger boxes), so if Mono performance is 2/3rds that of a Windows server it may still be the better option in the long run. For example, Windows Web Server licenses are around $500. If a server is about $1000 that means the cost of 3 Mono servers = the cost of 2 Windows Servers.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that website with "big" traffic could be http://www.orionsbelt.eu/ which is running on mono and nginx. However I doubt that they have 1M page views per month or anything close to that.

There are other [companies using mono](http://mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono) on heavy load stuff (not web related though), for example [Second Life](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Mono). IMHO lack of websites with big traffic running on mono is not the problem of mono itself, but it's rather related with successful business idea which may cause heavy usage of someones website.

Comment: i completely agree  with you on the last point.And i know about second life using mono for the scripting purposes.But when u host a web application,then you may face problems because Mono doesn't have a great GC and it's not intensively tested as asp.net on iis

Comment: Current Mono Boehm GC will be replaced by the new Generational GC which is planned to be default in version 3.0 (although it is available to download from svn now I think). I don't know about any web based performance issues of the current one, only that mono fastcgi server is sometimes causing thrashing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). This however doesn't relate to mod_mono and Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to get that kind of traffic?  Congratulations.

I do not know of any website with that much traffic using Mono but here are a couple of considerations:

The most similar load scenario might be seen by the Plastic Source Code Management tool since in that model you have a central server processing the load from distributed clients.  I do not believe that they have run into any reliability issues with Mono.  You could ask them about Mono under load though.

The ASP.NET MVC implementation in Mono uses the actual Microsoft code since MVC was released as Open Source.  The ASP.NET implementation in Mono has been solid for a while and is really pretty mature.

Most websites are IO limited which means that Mono is unlikely to be the limiting factor.  Mono is slower than .NET but for most stuff it is in the same ballpark.  The GC is certainly less efficient though.

You can load test Mono yourself.  In my experience, it stands up just fine.